# Formating slide

Tags: tables, beamer

i need help formatting this slide:

[image]

As you can see, the text above the first table isnt in the same line as the text above the second table. How can i put them in the same line? Heres the code that generated it:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\begin{document}
        % SLIDE 40
        \subsection{Sistema de 33 barras}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Resultados}
        \framesubtitle{Sistema de 33 barras (barras candidatas: 7, 8, 9 e 10) - Primeiro caso}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
Resultado com $w_1 = 0$, $w_2 = 0$ e $w_3 = 1$:
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\label{primeiro_caso_trintaetres_barras}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Filtro & Ordem Harmônica & Barra \\ \hline
1      & 5ª                    & 7     \\ \hline
2      & 3ª                    & 10     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
Perdas totais de potências ativas e reativas:
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\label{primeiro_caso_dezessete_barras}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$Antes$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$Depois$} &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$\Delta P_{total} (kW)$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1385,291} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1353,611} &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$\Delta Q_{total} (kvar)$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{395,617} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{387,007} &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
                       &                       &                       &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{minipage}
        \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}`. Also, why 5 cols?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right-hand `tabular` environment is defined to contain 5 columns, but it has only 3.; do get rid of the final two. Moreover, the right-hand `tabular` environment contains a lot of very clumsy and cluttery code which simply isn't needed. You should simplify it drastically, maybe along the lines shown in the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{array,siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={\text{,}}}
\begin{document}
% SLIDE 40
\subsection{Sistema de 33 barras}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Resultados}
\framesubtitle{Sistema de 33 barras (barras candidatas: 7, 8, 9 e 10) -- Primeiro caso}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"

\begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
\centering
Resultado com $w_1 = 0$, $w_2 = 0$ e $w_3 = 1$:

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Filtro & Ordem Harmônica & Barra  \\ \hline
1      & 5ª              & 7      \\ \hline
2      & 3ª              & 10     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.505\textwidth}
\centering
Perdas totais de potências ativas e reativas:

\begin{tabular}{|l|S[table-format=4.3]|S[table-format=4.3]|}
\hline
& {\textit{Antes}} & {\textit{Depois}} \\ 
\hline
$\Delta P_{\!total}$ (kW) & 1385,291 & 1353,611 \\ 
\hline
$\Delta Q_{total}$ (kvar) &  395,617 &  387,007 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 too :-). Since OP use labels for table I bother with adding templates for `caption` ...

Comment: Great, i got it now... thanks for all the info everyone!

Answer (score 6):

you have many issues with your slide:

- in beamer `table` environment is not a float, so it not need any positioning option (in your case `H`, which is ignored)
- referencing tables without having captions has no sense
- if you use \caption,referencing has sense if captions are numbered
- use `\multicolumns` or each cell in the second table is superfluous
- in second table you define 5 columns but use only three ...
- I doubt that column headers in the second table have math variables, correct is use `\textit{Antes}` etc
- for vertical align of your tables you can add option `[t]` to `minipage`s or use `tabularx` as I do in the following MWE
- I also suggest to use `S` columns type in the second table

Considering aforementioned i suggest the following rewriting of your slide:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
%----
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
    \setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
%----

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
        % SLIDE 40
        \subsection{Sistema de 33 barras}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Resultados}
    \framesubtitle{Sistema de 33 barras (barras candidatas: 7, 8, 9 e 10) - Primeiro caso}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} @{}}
    \caption{Resultado com $w_1 = 0$, $w_2 = 0$ e $w_3 = 1$:}
    \label{primeiro_caso_trintaetres_barras}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
Filtro  & Ordem Harmônica   & Barra \\ \hline
1       & 5ª                & 7     \\ \hline
2       & 3ª                & 10    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
&
    \caption{Perdas totais de potências ativas e reativas:}
    \label{primeiro_caso_dezessete_barras}
\begin{tabular}{|>{$}l<{$}|S|S|}
    \hline
    & {\textit{Antes}}  & {\textit{Depois}} \\ 
    \hline
\Delta P_{\mathrm{total}} (kW)
    &   1385,291        &   1353,611        \\ 
    \hline
\Delta Q_{\mathrm{total}} (kVAr)
    &   395,617         &   387,007         \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Maybe take the units (kW, kVAr) out of math mode?

Comment: @Mico, you are right. units should be in upright font, corrected.